# Fatal error in system's core file: Allowed memory exhausted (tried to allocate ...) in C:\...\system\core\Output.php on line 164

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got this error that makes my script take longer than usual to execute. I've tried to go through posts with similar errors but the advice I'm getting out of them is to allocate more or unlimited memory size of which others claim might cause problems in future. I tried checking my XAMPP control panel and noticed there was an errror "Not logged in as an administrator" so I fixed that but still the memory error won't be fixed, I tried going through my code but everything seemed to be fine since the system is supposed to use a single form for both inserting and updating data into the database and ofcourse it does so but takes longer than usual to execute. I've I messed up my code or is there a way out of this instead of cheating with allocating more or unlimited memory? I'm using CodeIgniter on windows 7. Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance. Find below my code snippets.
**N/B:** Consider function update_institution_contact_info() as dummy since I haven't worked on it, it's there to portray the idea to be implemented.

controller - vetting.php

```
    public function create_institution_contact_info()
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'institution_contact_info_view';
    $data['method'] = 'create_institution_contact_info';
    $this->load->model('institution_users_model');
    $data['form_data'] = $this->institution_users_model->get_institution_contact_info();
    $data['title'] = 'Institution Contact Information';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'institution_registration_no', 
        'Institution Registration Number', 
        'trim|required|is_unique[institution_contact_info.institution_registration_no]'
    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('institution_address', 'Institution Address', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('institution_telephone_no', 'Institution Telephone Number', 'trim|required');

    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        //$this->load->model('institution_users_model');
        $create_institution_contact = $this->institution_users_model->create_institution_contact(); 

        if($create_institution_contact)
        {
            redirect('vetting/basic_info');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->create_institution_contact_info();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->create_institution_contact_info();
    }

}

public function update_institution_contact_info()
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'institution_contact_info_view';
    $data['method'] = 'update_institution_contact_info';
    $this->load->model('institution_users_model');
    $data['form_data'] = $this->institution_users_model->get_institution_contact_info();
    $data['title'] = 'Update Institution Contact Information';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'institution_registration_no', 
        'Institution Registration Number', 
        'trim|required|is_unique[institution_contact_info.institution_registration_no]'
    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('institution_address', 'Institution Address', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('institution_telephone_no', 'Institution Telephone Number', 'trim|required');

    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        //$this->load->model('institution_users_model');
        $create_institution_contact = $this->institution_users_model->create_institution_contact(); 

        if($create_institution_contact)
        {
            redirect('vetting/basic_info');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->create_institution_contact_info();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->create_institution_contact_info();
    }

}
```

model - institution_users_model.php

```
    public function get_institution_users_id() 
{
    //Get each logged_in user's current session_id
    $email_address = $this->session->userdata('email_address');
    if($email_address){
        $this->db->where('institution_users.email_address', $email_address);
        $institution_users = $this->db->get('institution_users');   
        foreach($institution_users->result() as $row)
        {
            $institution_users_id = $row->institution_users_id;
        }
        return $institution_users_id;
    }       
}

public function create_institution_contact()
{                               
    $contact_data = array(
        'institution_users_id' => $this->get_institution_users_id(),
        'institution_registration_no' => $this->input->post('institution_registration_no'),
        'institution_address' => $this->input->post('institution_address'),
        'institution_telephone_no' => $this->input->post('institution_telephone_no'),
        'website' => $this->input->post('website')
    );

    $insert_contact = $this->db->insert('institution_contact_info', $contact_data);
    if($insert_contact)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
} 

public function get_institution_contact_info()
{
    $this->db->where('institution_contact_info.institution_users_id', $this->get_institution_users_id());
    $institution_contact_info = $this->db->get('institution_contact_info');
    if($institution_contact_info->num_rows()>0)
    {
        $row = $institution_contact_info->row();
        return $row;
    }               
}
```

View - institution_contact_info.php

```
            <div class="form">

            <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
            <form method="post" action="vetting/<?php echo $method; ?>">
                <label for="institution_registration_no">Institution Registration Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="institution_registration_no" value="<?php if(isset($form_data->institution_registration_no)){ echo $form_data->institution_registration_no; } ?>" />
                <label for="institution_address">Address/Location</label>
                <input type="text" name="institution_address" />
                <label for="institution_telephone_no">Institution Telephone Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="institution_telephone_no" />
                <label for="website">Website</label>
                <input type="text" name="website" />
                <input type="submit" name="next_submit" value="NEXT" data-theme="a" data-corners="false" />                                                         
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: which line is 164 of Output.php?

Comment: Here is a snippet of the function involved and remember it's CodeIgniter's core framework file.  `code`function append_output($output)
 {
  if ($this->final_output == '')
  {
   $this->final_output = $output;
  }
  else
  {
   $this->final_output .= $output;
  }

  return $this;
 } N/B: This is line 164: $this->final_output .= $output;